# Possible Electrostatic interference with HDMI connection

Tags: interference, hdmi, display, laptop

First I'm sorry if I'am posting this in the wrong way.

The problem that I have is this:

I have a monitor, Asus VZ249H, brand new. And a laptop, a Clevo Laptop with a nVidia GTX 970M. Windows 10 64 bits, and I mostly use the "expand desktop" option on windows configuration.

The problem that I'm having is related with some signal losses that I have while using the laptop in a normal way. For instance, if I'm playing a game, like CS:GO, the monitor works perfectly without any faults. But, if I'm working, sometimes the monitor loses the signal (turns black) and in a less than a second, has the signal again (even says HDMI connection when he recovers the signal).

I really doubt that the problem is with the monitor or with the laptop.

However, I do believe that might be because of the HDMI cable (was the cheapest one that I found: http://www.equip-info.de/N-A/119340/p-1016.htm ) or with my electrical instalation.

In my room, I don't have any wall plug with ground connection. I know, that the laptop generates some electrostatic, so can be the problem related with that?

Can the electrostatic produced by the monitor, or laptop, interfere with the HDMI signal connection?

Can the fact that I don't have a ground connection in my room where I connect both the monitor and the laptop, be the reason for this?

In fact, if I'm using my latptop without his AC Transformer, the monitor doesn't have any problem. It starts randomly with the AC Transformer connected to the laptop.

Thanks everyone for your attention.

Best regards

EDIT: So I've tried with a new HDMI cable and I've also tried to turn ON only the DISCRETE graphic card on my laptop, to avoid possible conflits between the nVidia and Intel graphic card.
I've noticed that the frequency of the anomalies reduced a lot. Maybe I am in the right path.
Only thing left to try is to connect a ground cable to my room. I'm thinking of connecting the ground cable to the water pipes of my bathroom.

Comment: What "AC Transformer"? Transforming what to what?

Comment: More like a power supply problem. E.g. if I connect something big to the wall and cause a spark, my monitor sometimes goes black. Fridge and AC are also two source of interference.

Comment: @AliChen My laptop AC Transformer, that transforms 230 V AC to 19.5 V DC. Both laptop and monitor transformers have a ground prong on the connectors. My house does not have any type of ground installation. When I talked about the "AC Transformer", I was talking about the monitor problem doesn't occur, while my laptop is working with his battery.

Comment: @user3528438 Yes I really think that might be some electrical problem.

I know that my laptop produces electrostatic energy, specially when is connected to a wall plug without ground.
And I know this, because my Clevo laptop has an aluminium case. So sometimes if I put my wrist near the case (but don't touch it), I can feel some "tickle". A related thing happens with a jack headphones connected to the laptop where I can hear a static noise, but if I touch anywhere the laptop that noise is gone because I'm a conductor myself. So I know that there is some electrostatic in my laptop.

Comment: My doubt is, if that electrostatic can interfere with the HDMI signal?

Answer (score 0):

"if I'm using my latptop without his AC Transformer, the monitor doesn't have any problem. It starts randomly with the AC Transformer connected to the laptop."

I have seen issues like this, and it was due to a static electricity buildup in a dry winter environment. A humidifier would almost certainly solve this.

It's common knowledge that when we shuffle our shoes across the carpet in the winter, we build up such a charge. When we then touch a grounded metal object, we experience a painful shock as a spark jumps from our finger to a doorknob or faucet.

With the wall transformer, there is no path to ground between the AC plug and the DC plug to dissipate a static electricity charge (which can be in the hundreds or thousands of volts). The resistance between those points is usually in the gigohm range.

My experienced guess is that with a direct connection, there's a path to ground to dissipate the static charge. Therefore, there is no static to produce these problems.

Without more details, I can't say for certain this is the case, but I would almost be willing to bet that's the issue here.

Comment: Exactly, that was what I was thinking. The electrostatic might be the cause of the HDMI interference. In fact, right now, my laptop is connected to his AC Transformer, and is charging his battery while I am using it. Since then, I've got no problems with my screen. However, I betting that when my battery is all charged up, all the energy will be used by the laptop itself and not by the laptop and the battery charging circuit.

In fact, I'm starting to notice two things. While I'm using my laptop with his full power (like playing a game), I have no problem with the HDMI connection.

Comment: However, if I use the laptop to do normal things, like work or browsing the web, the problem start to occur. 
It's like in these times might be a residual charge (like a little excess of energy) that is acting like electrostatic (I'm afraid that I am explaining me wrong, I'm sorry if that is the case).

Comment: And that charge might be being used by the HDMI port and cable, so the monitor feels that signal inconsistency and loses his connection momentaneously.

For instance, right now while my laptop is charging, I'm typing this, and have some other tab's opened on my Firefox browser.  I also have an ear headphones connected to laptop by is jack port. I'm not listening any sound, but I can listen a very faint sound. And if I touch the chassis of my laptop, that faint sound stops.

Comment: This means that there is indeed an electrostatic charge in my laptop, that can't be "discharged" because there is no ground connection on my wall plug.

So how can I do a ground connection in my room, without any ground installation in the entire house?

Thank you so much for your reply @MikeWaters

Comment: @Pirilampus Your two-prong plug still has a neutral.

Comment: Yes indeed, but isn't that a little dangerous? If somehow someone in the rest of the house has a problem that can possibly energize the Neutral cable, like a short-circuit or something, that will not be a problem?
Another thing: the ground cable should not have any kind of interruptor, because is the "excape" way. If I directly connect a wire between the Neutral and the Ground, and install a ground compatible wall plug, the Ground becomes protected by that interruptor, so if something happens the interruptor will open and I then have a open Ground.
Thank you for your help